# How to change decimal places of a factor variable in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, visualization, data-manipulation

I would like change decimal places on x and y axis to two instead of one. For example, I need `17.11` instead of `17.1`. The problem is my x and y axis are factor variables, so I can't seem to change the decimal places. I tried to convert `mean_temp` and `total_count` to numeric, but got NAs.

Here is the heatmap

[image]

Here is the reproducible example used to create the above figure

```
df <- structure(
  list(
    total_count = c(
      10L,
      0L,
      15L,
      0L,
      20L,
      0L,
      0L,
      50L,
      0L,
      6L,
      1L,
      10L,
      7L,
      0L,
      0L,
      29L,
      0L,
      2L,
      11L,
      3L,
      0L,
      12L,
      0L,
      30L,
      0L,
      0L,
      29L,
      44L,
      10L,
      5L,
      2L,
      145L,
      0L,
      70L
    ),
    mean_temp = c(
      18.87,
      18.87,
      18.87,
      18.87,
      18.87,
      18.87,
      18.87,
      18.87,
      18.87,
      21.85,
      21.85,
      21.85,
      21.85,
      21.85,
      21.85,
      21.85,
      21.85,
      21.85,
      17.11,
      17.11,
      17.11,
      17.11,
      17.11,
      17.11,
      17.11,
      17.11,
      18.82,
      18.82,
      18.82,
      18.82,
      18.82,
      18.82,
      18.82,
      18.82
    ),
    lwd_duration = c(
      64.32,
      64.32,
      64.32,
      64.32,
      64.32,
      64.32,
      64.32,
      64.32,
      64.32,
      104.2,
      104.2,
      104.2,
      104.2,
      104.2,
      104.2,
      104.2,
      104.2,
      104.2,
      53.53,
      53.53,
      53.53,
      53.53,
      53.53,
      53.53,
      53.53,
      53.53,
      60.43,
      60.43,
      60.43,
      60.43,
      60.43,
      60.43,
      60.43,
      60.43
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-34L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
  na.action = structure(
    c(
      `4` = 4L,
      `5` = 5L,
      `6` = 6L,
      `7` = 7L,
      `8` = 8L,
      `9` = 9L,
      `78` = 78L,
      `87` = 87L,
      `96` = 96L,
      `105` = 105L,
      `114` = 114L,
      `123` = 123L,
      `132` = 132L,
      `141` = 141L,
      `150` = 150L,
      `159` = 159L,
      `168` = 168L,
      `177` = 177L,
      `186` = 186L,
      `849` = 849L,
      `850` = 850L,
      `851` = 851L,
      `852` = 852L,
      `891` = 891L,
      `892` = 892L,
      `893` = 893L,
      `894` = 894L,
      `921` = 921L,
      `922` = 922L,
      `923` = 923L,
      `924` = 924L,
      `937` = 937L,
      `938` = 938L,
      `939` = 939L,
      `940` = 940L,
      `969` = 969L,
      `970` = 970L,
      `971` = 971L,
      `972` = 972L,
      `985` = 985L,
      `986` = 986L,
      `987` = 987L,
      `988` = 988L,
      `1017` = 1017L,
      `1018` = 1018L,
      `1019` = 1019L,
      `1020` = 1020L,
      `1033` = 1033L,
      `1034` = 1034L,
      `1035` = 1035L,
      `1036` = 1036L
    ),
    class = "omit"
  )
)
```

Code used to create the figure

```
dat2 <-
  df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(
    mean_temp = cut_interval(mean_temp, n = 10),
    total_count = cut_interval(total_count, n = 10),
  ) %>%
  group_by(mean_temp, total_count) %>%
  summarize(lwd_duration = mean(lwd_duration))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'mean_temp'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.

ggplot(dat2, aes(mean_temp, total_count)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = lwd_duration)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(lwd_duration, 1))) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red")
```

**Note:** I'd be happy with whole numbers too, if changing decimal places is not possible. The main objective is to ensure uniformity and consistency among the values displayed on both the x and y axes, as the complete figure contains both one and two decimal places (I cannot paste the entire dataset here due to space constraints). Thanks

Comment: You might look at `dig.lab` parameter for the call to `cut_interval()`?

Comment: @langtang what value do I set `dig. lab` to? I tried `0.2` but got extremely large numbers on the axes. Thanks

Comment: 2 ? (2 decimals)

Comment: tried 2 as well. Same issue

Comment: its not great, because you have to set to 4, because its the total digits, instead of decimal places. Also, it doesn't use a fixed formatting, so `10` doesn't become `10.00` (it remains as a whole number)

Comment: @langtang yes, it didn't work. `10` became `10.1`, so my problem consistency problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `dig.lab` (in `cut_intevals()`) to an integer that is sufficiently high, such as `4` or `5`.  Then, you can subsequently use this little function to standardize the labels generated by `cut_interval`

```
standardize_cut_levels <- function(l, dig=2) {
  sapply(l, \(s) {
    m = gregexpr("\\d+\\.?\\d{0,}",s)
    m = regmatches(s,m)[[1]]
    r = sub(m[1], trimws(sprintf(paste0("%9.", dig, "f"), as.numeric(m[1]))),s)
    sub(m[2], trimws(sprintf(paste0("%9.", dig, "f"), as.numeric(m[2]))),r)
  })
}
```

Now, after you create `dat2`, simply call this function like this:

```
levels(dat2$mean_temp) <- standardize_cut_levels(levels(dat2$mean_temp))
levels(dat2$total_count) <- standardize_cut_levels(levels(dat2$total_count))
```

Now your plotting code will produce this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get full control of the appearances, I would probably use string parsing. This includes removal of the brackets, which are helpful from a technical point of view, but often confusing or cluttered on a plot.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat2 %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  separate(mean_temp, into = c("a", "b"), sep = ",") %>%
  separate(total_count, into = c("c", "d"), sep = ",") %>%
  mutate(across(1:4, ~as.numeric(str_remove(., "\\[|\\(|\\]|\\)")))) %>%
  mutate(across(1:4, ~ sprintf("%.2f", .))) %>%
  mutate(mean_temp = paste(a, b, sep = " - ")) %>%
  mutate(total_count = paste(c, d, sep = " - ")) %>%
  dplyr::select(c(6, 7, 5)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(mean_temp, total_count)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = lwd_duration)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(lwd_duration, 1))) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: @Ahsk I know that - it's just that plots are used for illustration, and this is a subtlety that can usually be skipped over when presenting your .data